# Wordpress web invoice 2checkout redirect

Tags: wordpress, invoice, 2checkout

I have 2checkout account running in demo mode and have just integrated 2checkout with wordpress plugin web invoice. The invoice is being generated perfectly but when the user completes the transaction and is redirected back to my website, it displays an error message "Invoice not found". The invoice status is also not being updated to paid. I have tried all three redirect methods in the 2checkout admin dashboard. Currently I've set it to "Give Link Back". Am I supposed to add some code on the checkout page in wordpress or have i missed some setting in the web invoice config page?

[This](http://www.assignmentspro.com/checkout/?invoice_id=e3a8153b837128505cd9089b6bbd1413) is the link to the invoice:

The error that I have mentioned only appears after the completion of the transaction at 2checkout is completed and the user is redirected back to my website.

Answer (score 0):

Web Invoice passes the approved URL in dynamically with the `invoice_id` appended like "http://www.yoursite.com/sample-page/?invoice_id=31540985dec0e37bd0142e34856ee1df". if the domain in this URL does not match the domain that you have set on your 2Checkout account, it will not be used and the invoice will not be able to be found.

My suggestion is to check and make sure that the domain matches the domain you have registered to your 2Checkout account. If you are just using a 2Checkout demo account, you can fill in the first page of the signup application on your account homepage by clicking on the Apply Now button and save your changes to set a URL for your demo account.

As always please don't hesitate to contact techsupport@2co.com for assistance with your testing.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Craig. I did what you said but it is still giving me the same error. What I did was that I started an application at 2co and added www.assignmentspro.com in the URL. It's also showing up in the account page now. I have set the Return to "give link back". The approved URL is set to www.assignmentspro.com/checkout. I've created another invoice for testing: http://www.assignmentspro.com/checkout/?invoice_id=a938512fe77b2911e742eb6df118d1f5 
Am I doing something wrong here? Again am i supposed to receive any parameters manually or should web invoice do it automatically?

Comment: The passback is working properly on your 2Checkout account and the invoice id is being passed in the query string on the passback but the invoice is not being recognized by your install. I am not able to replicate the issue using a 2Checkout demo account on my own install so I suggest that you please contact 2Checkout directly so that we can continue troubleshooting the issue with you. I'll be happy to update this thread once we figure out a resolution to help others.

Comment: Try changing the return method on your 2Checkout Site Management page to "Header Redirect". This return method works for me. You will also need to place a live sale to insure that the MD5 hash matches up. Let me know how it goes.